Can I do remote debugging with PyCharm and Visual Studio Code on the same server?
I have some C++ and Python code which I sometimes want to debug. I have a server to which I connect my debugger using ssh. All my code in on the server.
I use Visual Studio Code for both C++ and Python for now; I wonder if I can switch to PyCharm for Python. I want to retain the ability to debug my C++ code using Visual Studio Code.
Is this possible? If yes, are there any obvious caveats? Like maybe I need to use different ports somehow?
I tried setting it up, but got many problems. I am trying to understand if it's possible at all; if yes, I'll try to fix all these small problems.
